# How to not use any in React-Native Fast-Image Component TypeScript

Tags: typescript, image, react-native, types

I have a component that will show an Image, It will receive an url and style.

```
interface FastImageProps {
  styleComponent: StyleProp<ImageStyle> | StyleProp<ImageStyle>[];
  url: string;
}

export const FastImageComponent: React.FC<FastImageProps> = ({
  styleComponent,
  url,
}: any) => {

  return (
    <FastImage
      style={styleComponent}
      source={{
        uri: `WEB_PATH/${url}`,
        priority: FastImage.priority.normal,
        cache: FastImage.cacheControl.immutable,
      }}
      resizeMode={FastImage.resizeMode.cover}
    />
  );
};
```

it is working properly, but the component is using any. if i remove the any, the style will have a red line and show this

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: FastImageProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<FastImageProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> | RecursiveArray<false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> | null | undefined> | StyleProp<...>[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ImageStyle>'.
      Type 'ImageStyle' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ImageStyle>'.
        Type 'import("PATH/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ImageStyle' is not assignable to type 'import("PATH/node_modules/react-native-fast-image/dist/index").ImageStyle'.
          Types of property 'backgroundColor' are incompatible.
            Type 'string | unique symbol | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
              Type 'unique symbol' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<FastImageProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | Component<FastImageProps, any, any> | null', gave the following error.
    Type 'false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> | RecursiveArray<false | ImageStyle | RegisteredStyle<ImageStyle> | null | undefined> | StyleProp<...>[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ImageStyle>'.
      Type 'ImageStyle' is not assignable to type 'StyleProp<ImageStyle>'.
        Type 'import("PATH/node_modules/@types/react-native/index").ImageStyle' is not assignable to type 'import("PATH/node_modules/react-native-fast-image/dist/index").ImageStyle'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(77, 5): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastImageProps'
index.d.ts(77, 5): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastImageProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'
```

here is how i call my component

```
<FastImageComponent
 styleComponent={{width: sizeWidth(20), height: sizeWidth(20)}}
 url={imageUrl}/>
```

can anybody explain to me why this is happening? and What changes do i need to make the component not using any.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can import `ImageStyle` from `react-native-fast-image` and use that instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, i found the answer. I cannot use the ImageStyle from 'react-native'.

i need to declare it manually like this

```
export interface ImageStyle {
  backfaceVisibility?: 'visible' | 'hidden';
  borderBottomLeftRadius?: number;
  borderBottomRightRadius?: number;
  backgroundColor?: string;
  borderColor?: string;
  borderWidth?: number;
  borderRadius?: number;
  borderTopLeftRadius?: number;
  borderTopRightRadius?: number;
  overlayColor?: string;
  tintColor?: string;
  opacity?: number;
}
```

and when i delete the any, it wont show the error now.